# Is more cargo loaded if there is less passengers than expected?

Tags: airliner, weight-and-balance, commercial-operations

When pre-flight weigh in is done, if the plane weighs less than expected because people don't turn up, is more cargo added?

Conversely - if the plane is over the estimated weight - does cargo get removed?  Passenger bags removed?  Passengers removed?

Is it within the airline's strategy to achieve 100% seat capacity utilisation?

Comment: There's what *should* happen, and there is what can happen if/when people in charge for one reason or another don't care (and the consequences this can have). See e.g. [PBS Frontline broadcasted 2010-02-09, titled *Flying Cheap*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-zq41c2EbCA) at about 43 minutes into the video.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You pose several scenarios.

> Is more cargo added if people do not show up?

No. By the time a person does not show up, the cargo is usually already delivered and loaded on the aircraft.

> If the plane is over the estimated weight - does cargo get removed? Passenger bags removed? Passengers removed?

Yes, although passengers almost always have priority. On heavy cargo flights, the cargo department will send a priority list if the load planners need to bump cargo.

> Is it within the airline's strategy to achieve 100% seat capacity utilisation?

Absolutely, although on payload restricted flights, non-revenue passengers may not always priority over cargo. This depends on the route. Many long-haul flights, if payload restricted, a scenario could happen where a staff member traveling as a non-revenue passenger will not be accepted because accepting them would exceed the max payload for the flight.

Comment: While non-revenue passengers do not always have priority over cargo, most of them have priority over *everything*. Because most of these are crews that will man another flight from where they are heading, mechanics that are needed to fix a broken plane there and such and will incur *huge loss* if *not* transported.